# Doesn't need anything between be-verb and to one's advantage?

Tags: intransitive-verbs

I saw a sentence with idiom "to one's advantage" in my textbook.

*After that, It was obviously to my advantage*.

When I saw this, I thought "why isn't there any complement after *was*?"

I thought *Obviously* and *to my advantage* were all adverb. But then where is complement of *was*?

Or is that *was* used as intransitive verb that means "exist"?

If then so, can I call that "Be + to N Phrase?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *After that, it was **obviously** to my advantage.*

The complement of "was" is *obviously to my advantage*.

Adverbs can certainly function as modifiers in copular verb phrases.

The natural analysis of your example has the adverb in bold as an adjunct in clause structure. Note examples like:

*I was **at that time** extremely happy*.

*I was **when I met her** much happier than I had been for several years.*

Comment: Great. So you mean it can be used as modifier if it doesn't appear to be adjunct then.

Comment: "Obviously" is an adjunct. It modifies the VP "was to my advantage".

Comment: Yeah, I see that. Thanks for help!